# How are functors in Haskell related to functors in category theory?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

For as far as I understand, a functor is a mapping between two categories, for example from objects in [image: C] to objects in [image: D] where [image: C] and [image: D] are categories.

In Haskell there is **Hask** in which the objects are Haskell types and the morphisms are Haskell functions. However, the `Functor` type class has a function `fmap` which maps between these *types* (which are thus objects and not categories themselves):

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`f a` and `f b` are both objects in **Hask**. Does this mean every instance of `Functor` in Haskell is an endofunctor, and if not does `Functor` really represent a functor?

What am I missing here? Are types also categories in Haskell?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An instance of `Functor` specifies two things: a type constructor `F` of kind `* -> *`, that is, a mapping from objects of Hask to objects of Hask, and a function of type `(a -> b) -> (F a -> F b)`, that is, a mapping from arrows of Hask to arrows of Hask compatible with the object-mapping `F`. So, yes, all instances of `Functor` are endofunctors. There are several generalizations available on Hackage, e.g. [Control.Categorical.Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/categories/1.0.5/doc/html/Control-Categorical-Functor.html).

Comment: You say *arrows of Hask compatible with the object-mapping `F`*. Is that a subcategory of Hask?

Comment: @Zoidberg Yup, it's the subcategory of Hask whose objects are the types whose outermost type constructor is `F`.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: theoretically these endofunctors not necessarily must work on types with kind `* -> *`, I mean functor could map a function `Int -> Char` to function `String -> Double`. As I understand, in theory functors work on any morphisms. But I guess that's not too practical. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: @dimsuz Hm. I'm fuzzy on exactly what you're proposing with your `Int -> Char`/`String -> Double` comment. Your other comment is also making me squint: you seem to be implying that there are morphisms that the existing `Functor` instances do not work on, but this is not correct. So I suspect there is still some misunderstanding; but I'm having trouble pinpointing exactly where. If you gave some more details about what source and target categories you were considering with your "map a function" comment, and what morphisms you think aren't mapped by existing `Functor`s, I could say more.

Comment: my line of thoughts: the definition of functor: maps objects to objects, maps functions to functions (in Hask). So potentially some functor can map any function in this category to any other function in this category. So *potentially* there can be functor which maps some `Int -> Char` to `String -> Double`. I.e. `a -> b` to `c -> d`. Or is this false? I understand that Functor maps `a -> b` to `F a -> F b`, but could there ever be a functor which does the mapping without using a type constructor on the other end? Again, I mean at least in theory.

Comment: @dimsuz Yes, that would be allowed. Of course there are *some* rules about the mappings -- notably that the mapping on functions has to be compatible with the mapping on objects -- but the particular proposal you made doesn't obviously violate that rule yet. Modern Haskell even *almost* makes it possible via type families; languages that support first-class type-level functions would support it pretty naturally.

Comment: thank you for clarification! Wanted to confirm that I got at least these basic points understood more or less right...

Answer (score 19):

Yes, all `Functor` instances are endofunctors on **Hask**--in fact, endofunctors from all of **Hask** to a proper subcategory whose objects are the types obtained by applying a particular type constructor. That type constructor is what the `Functor` instance is associated with, and gives the mapping for objects; the mapping for morphisms is `fmap`, which (because we're only concerned with endofunctors on a cartesian closed category) is itself a family of morphisms in **Hask**.

It does make sense to consider other functors besides those which can have `Functor` instances, such as [contravariant functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contravariant/0.4/doc/html/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html) (from **Hask** to its opposite category). The `arr` function in [the `Arrow` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html) also corresponds to a functor, from all of **Hask** to the category whose objects are the same as those of **Hask** and whose morphisms are described by the type constructor the `Arrow` instance is associated with.

Further generalizations are also possible (as Daniel Wagner notes), but tend to become increasingly awkward to use.

Answer (score 4):

One important point about this is that what you really want is functors **enriched** in **Hask**, not just plain old functors. **Hask** is cartesian closed ([not really](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/10/what-category-do-haskell-types-and.html?showComment=1255861175804#c3365363734200015962), but it tries hard to be onesuch), and so it is naturally enriched in itself.

Now, enriched endofunctors give you a way of restricting to those *implementable within the language*: an enriched functor **Hask -> Hask** is a function at the level of objects (types) `f a` and for each pair of objects `a, b` a morphism in **Hask** going *f : **Hask**(a,b) -> **Hask**(fa,fb)*. Of course, this is just `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`