# Why doesn't Haskell's `Functor` instance define a "return-like" function?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In Category Theory, a Functor is a morphism between categories, that is, it maps each object in category `A` to another object in `B`, as well as mapping each morphism `C -> D` onto the respective objects in `B`, while preserving composition of morphisms. So one could say a functor is composed of two "parts", one that maps Objects to Objects, and one that maps Morphisms to Morphisms.
In Haskell if I understood it properly, each Type in The `Functor` typeclass can be "mapped onto", that is a function of Type `a -> b` can be mapped onto a function `F a -> F b`. Now why doesn't there exist a `return :: Functor f => a -> f a` function, specifically for `Functor`? Is there no need, since we can simply utilize the definition of `return` in the `Monad` instance, since return is really only working on the functor part of a Monad, or is there another reason?

It striked me as strange, because if that were the way, why would't `return` be included in the `Functor` instance? I mean every monad has a functor part, so to me, that would make sense. Can anyone enlighten me in that matter?

Comment: In category theory, a functor in general does not allow `return::a->F a` for all `a`. E.g., in the category of sets, defining `F a = emptySet` (and `F anyMorphism = identity_emptySet`) constructs a functor, but no `a -> F a` is possible for nonempty `a`.

Comment: There is in fact a `Pointed` typeclass in `data.pointed` with `point :: a -> p a`. But not every functor can be made into an instance of `Pointed`, for example `data Void a deriving Functor` (essentially for reasons given by @chi)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192985/745903 for an alternative implementation of the `Functor` class in which the "objects to objects" mapping appears explicitly. (And it is very different from `return`.)

Comment: In Haskell, type class resolution is type-directed so the structure of a `Functor f`-instance is determined by `f`. `f` itself is the object-mapping (mapping `Type -> Type`) and `fmap @f` is the arrow-mapping (maps `a -> a'` to `f a -> f a'`). Those are the two mappings, and the object-mapping determines the arrow-mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a common misconception and one that used to trip me up. You're right that a functor has two parts: one that maps objects to objects and one that maps functions to functions (more generally, arrows to arrows, but that's not really germane here). Now, when I have

```
instance Functor F where
    fmap f x = ...
```

You've already correctly surmised that `fmap` takes functions to functions. However, we *already* have a way to take objects to objects. Categorically, our objects are not *values*, they're *types*. So the "objects to objects" part is something that should map a type to another type. And that thing is called `F`. The name of our functor literally *is* the mapping from objects to objects. Given a type `a`, the type `F a` is some other type lifted by our functor.

Now that raises the fair question: What *is* `return`? It takes an `a` and produces an `F a` (for a monad `F`). More specifically, given a fixed monad `F`, the signature is

```
return :: forall a. a -> F a
```

Now carefully read that. That says "given any *type* `a`, I can come up with a function from `a` to `F a`". That is, it takes an *object* in our category (a type) and maps it into an arrow in our category (a function). A mapping from an object to an arrow is called a [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation), and that's exactly what `return` is.

Categorically speaking, a *monad* is a functor (the underlying type `F` together with `fmap`), together with two natural transformations:

- `return`, which is a natural transformation `1 -> F` (where `1` is the identity functor), and
- `join`, which is a natural transformation `F^2 -> F` (where `F^2` is `F` composed with itself)

That is, for any type `a`, `return` has type `a -> F a` and `join` has type `F (F a) -> F a`<sup>[1]</sup>.

What would a typeclass with `return` and `fmap` look like? I'm not sure. I don't know of a Haskell library that implements that typeclass, and I'm not entirely sure what the laws would look like. A good guess might be `fmap f . return === return . f`, but we actually get that as a [free theorem](https://archive.org/details/theorems_for_free/mode/2up), so that's not our law. If you or someone else knows of this typeclass somewhere in the Hackage ecosystem, feel free to let me know.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Haskell uses an equivalent definition of "monad" in terms of the bind operator `(>>=)` rather than `join`. They're equivalent mathematically, and I opted for the simpler definition here.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean when saying "return" maps any type to an arrow or function? What does this function look like?

Comment: Given any type `a`, `return` produces a function of type `a -> f a`. Usually we just think of `return` as *being* a function from `a -> f a`, but that's because Haskell hides the `forall a` in front. But there's a hidden type parameter out there. If you're comfortable with [TypeApplications](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html), you can make the type argument explicit. For instance (in the specific case of `Monad Maybe`), `return` is a polymorphic function, but `return @Int` has type `Int -> Maybe Int` and is a single conrete function.

Comment: Last question, so really we specify the type e.g. `a` that we want to "lift" into the monad, and then "return" returns/gives us the function of type `a -> M a`. If thats the case a lot of stuff begins to make sense...

Comment: Exactly! And that's exactly what a natural transformation is, in category theory. It's a thing that, when you specify a type, you get a function that does something neat with that type.

Comment: One finally last thing, does that mean that every functor in Haskell is an endofunctor in the category of haskell types?

Comment: @AlSneed An endofunctor is just a functor from one category to itself (but not necessarily an identity functor; it could still map the objects and arrows to *different* objects and arrows in the same category). It's not actually a very interesting statement to a Haskell programmer, it's just saying that the `Functor` class can only map Haskell types to Haskell types, not to any different sort of category.

Comment: @AlSneed Haskell `Functor` is actually even more restricted than just "endofunctors on the category of Haskell types". A `Functor` always maps to a "subcategory". For example the entire structure of the category of Haskell types is mirrored under `Maybe` - for every distinct type `a` (including `Maybe` types!!) there is a distinct type `Maybe a`. A `Functor` always maps to a subcategory like that, it can't do any different sort of "rearranging" of Haskell types that a general endofunctor might be able to do.

Comment: Can I ask for a clarification? You say "A mapping from an object to an arrow is called a natural transformation, and that's exactly what return is." But your link explains a natural transformation as a mapping between *functors*, rather than a mapping from objects to arrows, and that seems to be how you're using it in the rest of the answer (e.g. where you say `return` is a natural transformation `1 -> F`, where `1` is the identity functor). It's not obvious to me how the two definitions of natural transformation are connected.

Comment: @Ben, note that the linked reference never refers to a *mapping* between functors.  If F and G are two functors each from category C to D, a natural transformation "from F to G" is not a mapping from F to G.  Rather, it is a collection of arrows indexed by objects in C.  For each x in C, it gives an arrow F(x)->G(x) in the category D.  So, it can be viewed as a mapping from objects in C to arrows in D.  Or, in Haskell, it can be viewed as a mapping from types (objects in Hask) to functions (arrows in Hask) that maps each type `a` to a function with signature `F a -> G a`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Right, that's making sense now (or re-making sense; I feel like I've learnt this about 5 times). And for `return` we're taking `F` as `Identity` and then leaving it out of the actual Haskell type because it's boring. I was used to natural transformations manifesting in Haskell as things with types like `(forall x. f x -> g x)`. Although technically it seems like it's not true that any old collection of arrows indexed by objects is definitely a natural transformation; a natural transformation *is* such a collection, but it has to meet some conditions to make the diagram commute.

Comment: @Ben Yes, you're right that not any old collection of arrows works. But in Haskell specifically, parametricity makes it impossible to create a collection of arrows that simultaneously is as polymorphic as necessary and violates the commuting diagrams.

Comment: @Ben Actually, funnily enough that's basically what I meant by "free theorems" above. In the "Theorems for Free" short paper I linked, Wadler explains that any function that can be written in a type system with *parametricity* and which takes a type argument is a (lax) natural transformation.